# How to install Podman windows by command line?

Tags: virtualization, podman

I am using windows 10 Home. But with this edition I am unable to use docker or oracle vm virtualbox. So can I use Podman in place of docker? If yes then what is it's command?

Comment: I guess your best option is virtualbox, or docker toolbox. Double check that VT support is turned on in BIOS / UEFI Setup, and try again to install virtualbox or docker. https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home/11722

Answer (score 4):

At this date, the answer is no, you cannot use podman to run containers on Windows 10 Home.

Podman is very much a Linux program at this point. This big issue that I see for podman is the file system layering code. Given that podman is developed by Red Hat, it will probably require a partnership with Microsoft to make this happen. In that regard, Microsoft is developing their own tools for containers.

Comment: Thanks John, but can i go for virtualisation in windows 10 home edition? Is there any possible way? Or i have to install another operating system like ubantu.

Comment: Windows 10 Home has no virtualization features. This means installing a product like Virtual Box or VMware. You can also upgrade to Pro if your hardware supports Hyper-V. Docker requires Hyper-V on Windows. Podman does not support Windows though. If you have the memory install Virtual Box. Inside install Ubuntu or CentOS. Then you can install podman, buildah, etc. in the VM OS.

Answer (score 1):

Now Podman is supported on Windows.
Refer: https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/podman-for-windows.md